Ruby OOP classes interaction: Which way to update instance variables?
I have 2 classes: Game and Player. This is a Tic-tac-toe game.
class Game
    attr_accessor :player_1, :player_2, :numbers, :board

    def initialize(player_1, player_2)
        @player_1 = player_1
        @player_2 = player_2
        @numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    end
end

class Player

    attr_reader :name
    attr_accessor :selection

    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
        @selection = []
    end

    def play(game)
        print "#{name}, please pick a number: "
        number = gets.chomp.to_i
        print "#{name} selected #{number}"
        puts
        
        selection << number
        index = game.numbers.find_index(number)

        if (name == 'player_1')
            game.numbers[index] = 'X'
        else
            game.numbers[index] = 'O'
        end
    end
end

Codes to initialise Player and Game:
p1 = Player.new('player_1')
p2 = Player.new('player_2')
game = Game.new(p1, p2)

I setup the Player in the way that whenever a player pick a number (example: with p1.play(game)), the number will be stored in selection of Player and numbers in Game will be updated with "x" / "o".
Once the steps above completed, I update :player_1 and :player_2 in Game with:
game.player_1 = p1 & game.player_2 = p2
Print out the game.player_1.selection and the result is expected. However, I skipped the game.player_1 = p1 & game.player_2 = p2 once by mistake and print game.player_1.selection again. To my surprise, the result for both ways is the same regardless I execute game.player_1 = p1 & game.player_2 = p2.
So I would like to get clarification, as a newbie to OOP world; what is the correct way to update player_1 / player_2 for my case? Thanks.

game.player_1 is p1 – both refer to the very same object. If you modify the object, the change is reflected by both of them (and any other variable which might also refer to that object).

@Stefan, do you mean game.player_1 will automatically be updated once I call p1.play(game)?

When assigning an object to one or more variables, the object isn’t copied. Each variable just references the object. Hence, if the object changes, all variables referring to that object will instantly reflect that change.

Unrelated, but note that you can determine if either player wins, at any point, with something like def win?(board) [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 6], [2, 5, 8], [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6].all? { |a| board.values_at(*a).uniq.size == 1; end.

Variables are used to refer to objects. You set the object by assigning it to the variable via =, e.g.:
a = "hello"

You can now refer to "hello" via a, e.g.
a << " world"

a #=> "hello world"

Because of this usage, you might think that you modified a. But this isn't quite correct. You actually modified the object, a is referring to, i.e. the string "hello" which then became "hello world".
This distinction is important when you assign an object to more than one variable, e.g.:
a = "hello"
b = a

a << " world"

a #=> "hello world"
b #=> "hello world"

b = a will make b refer to the same object, a is referring to. I think of it as:
variable  object
   a ───────┐
          "hello"
   b ───────┘

When calling a << " world" the object gets modified, i.e.:
variable  object
   a ───────┐
          "hello world"
   b ───────┘

Inspecting a and b afterwards merely shows that modification.


what is the correct way to update player_1 / player_2 for my case?

You don't have to. In your code, p1 and game.player_1 already refer to the same object, an instance of Player. Therefore, updating that player instance is all you have to do.
Setting game.player_1 = p1 is actually superfluous because game.player_1 already referred to p1. You were merely re-assigning the very same object.

TQ @Stefan for detail explanation.
